# ORA-21535 error - oracle timeout issue

Tags: oracle

I am getting the ORA-21535 error in Oracle Alert Log file intermittently. First few hours my application is working fine. After that I'm getting time out issue.

```
    TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out 
        ns secondary err code: 12560 
        nt main err code: 505 

    TNS-00505: Operation timed out 
        nt secondary err code: 110 
        nt OS err code: 0 

Client Address: XXXXXXXXX
```

Note: I do not have any other application log other than "alert Log".

Comment: Is there some repeating pattern with this issue -- like the time of the day? The query issued? The table accessed? Does other Oracle's session "timed out" simultaneously? Does all instances of your program timed-out randomly? Or is it only _one particular instance_ ?

Comment: It is occurred randomly. After that my application stopped without any exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe solve your problem by setting SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME parameter in the sqlnet.ora of your Oracle server.

With this parameter database will probe the application server every n minutes where n is the setting number.